# Update database structure with Django 1.5

Tags: database, django, django-1.5

I'm looking for the updated Django 1.5 command that can do the following action.

```
python manage.py reset <app>
```

What I want to do basically is `DROP` tables and `UPDATE` the database structure inside with a `manage.py command`.

The thing is that reset command is no longer working and

```
manage.py flush
```

or

```
manage.py sqlclear <app>
```

are just dropping the database / table content.

What's the updated `reset` version for Django 1.5?

Comment: I dont think there is a replacement, but you can look into [`flush`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/django-admin/#flush)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is South. South is a 3rd party tool, which may soon be integrated into Django, that assists you with database migrations and schema changes. As is stands, Django 1.5 does not deal with schema changes very well, if at all. The only way to adjust a schema in Django 1.5 is to add new models. You wouldn't want to engage in the practice of adding a new model to fulfill a desired table alteration or deletion.  Most developers turn to a 3rd part solution when they need to make schema adjustments.

See http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/about.html

See Tutorial http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part1.html#tutorial-part-1

South is database agnostic and deals with database migrations automatically for you. So if you change your schema it will detect it in models.py and make the appropriate changes. You can include South as an app to your Django project and install it through pip

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

As a MySQL alternative, you can create a `application.py` next to `manage.py` with the following code.

This will `DROP`, `CREATE`, and `UPDATE` your database with your `models.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb
import subprocess

dbname = "mydbname"

db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="username", passwd="superpassword", db=dbname)

cur = db.cursor() 

#Drop all database to Drop all tables
cur.execute("DROP DATABASE "+dbname)

#Recreate the DB
cur.execute("CREATE DATABASE "+dbname)

#Sync with manage.py
proc = subprocess.call(['python','manage.py','syncdb'])

print "\n\nFinished!"
```